# Como cargar archivos de un servidor ftp en mi web?

Tags: php

Necesito mostrar en mi sitio web un listado con los archivos que se encuentran en un servidor ftp, y que además estos se puedan abrir desde la web. Alguien me podria ayudar con esto.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stack**overflow** te invito a realizar el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer el sitio y ganar tu primer medalla, así mismo mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que formules preguntas adecuadas al sitio y no generes puntos negativos o reportes que terminen eliminando tu pregunta.

Comment: Puede ser tan sencillo como incluir en tu página un enlace tal que así: `<a href="ftp://direccion.del.servidor.ftp">Haz clic aquí para acceder a los contenidos del servidor ftp</a>`. Eso funcionará porque los navegadores "entienden" ftp como protocolo y pueden hablar directamente con el servidor ftp. Eso sí, tu servidor web se quita de en medio, por lo que no puedes personalizar el aspecto de lo que se muestra al usuario. Pero a lo mejor te vale así.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, @abulafia pero para acceder al ftp necesito un usuario y una contraseña, en ese caso como seria?

Comment: @NadialozanoSolis Aunque podría hacerse (el esquema `ftp://` permite incluir un nombre de usuario y contraseña) sería altamente inseguro, pues esos datos formarían parte de la URL del enlace y serían visibles para cualquiera. Me temo que en ese caso tendrás que hacer un script php que haga de pasarela (actúe como cliente FTP y convierta el resultado a HTML). No tengo experiencia con eso, pero de cualquier forma me parece mala idea ya que FTP es un protocolo inseguro al no usar criptografía (sigo...)

Comment: @NadialozanoSolis (...sigue) la contraseña del usuario FTP viajaría "en claro" por la red, entre el servidor PHP y el de FTP. A menos que ambos estén en una red local segura, y el ftp no tenga acceso desde fuera, lo veo inseguro

Comment: @NadialozanoSolis La biblioteca [php-ftp-client](https://github.com/Nicolab/php-ftp-client) tiene buena pinta.

Answer (score 1):

Si no entiendo mal en uno de los comentarios, el ftp está en otro servidor con lo que no es posible acceder normalmente con open_dir. En este caso se me ocurren dos soluciones:

. Montar la carpeta FTP en el servidor de la web. Aquí tienes una explicación detallada, aunque dependerá de tus servidores, si uno de ellos o los dos son windows, se haría muy distinto: https://www.tecmint.com/sshfs-mount-remote-linux-filesystem-directory-using-ssh/

. Acceder con ftp_connect de php

```
<?php
    $ftp_user_name = "TU_USUARIO";
    $ftp_user_pass = "TU_PASSWORD";
    $ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
    if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
        die("La conexión FTP ha fallado!");
    }
    echo "Directorio actual: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";
    if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, "DIRECTORIO/DE/FICHEROS/")) {
        echo "El directorio actual es: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "No se pudo cambiar al directorio\n";
    }
    $contents = ftp_mlsd($conn_id, ".");
    var_dump($contents); // Aquí puedes recorrer el array devuelto para mostrar los ficheros.
    ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Aquí puedes acceder a la documentación completa de comandos ftp: http://php.net/manual/es/ref.ftp.php

Para poder mostrar los ficheros al conectar con FTP, se me ocurre bajarlos temporalmente al servidor web para posteriormente enviarlo al usuario. Lo podrías conseguir con una petición ajax. Partiendo del array generado anteriormente muestras los ficheros en HTML con una clase download añadida:

```
<?php
    $contents = "EL ARRAY DEL FTP";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Listado</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <?php
                foreach($contents as $e) {
                    foreach($e as $file) {
                        echo "<li class='download'>" . $file["name"] . "</li>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $(".download").click(function() {
                    var file = $(this).html();
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "download.php",
                        data: {
                            file: file
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

En la parte PHP, solo tendrías que conectar al FTP, bajar el fichero con ftp_fget:

```
<?php
    $remote_file = $_POST["file"];
    $local_file = "CARPETA/TEMPORAL/" . $_POST["file"];
    $handle = fopen($local_file, 'w');
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
    ftp_fget($conn_id, $handle, $remote_file, FTP_ASCII, 0);
    ftp_close($conn_id);
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

Con esto ya tienes el fichero en $local_file con lo que puedes hacer un simple header("Location: " . $local_file); por ejemplo (o desde la parte AJAX con el .done, habiendo devuelto la ruta del fichero o usando la variable file), cambiando la ruta local por la accesible desde el navegador, logicamente la carpeta local tienes que ponerla accesible. Otra cosa importante es que si el fichero a bajar se pasa por POST o GET, se puede solicitar bajar cualquier cosa del servidor, con lo que es importante tenerlo en cuenta para proteger ese vector de ataque.